# How do I increase/decrease mobile bid criteria for adgroups for Google AdWords API?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

So far this is what I have tried.

```
    $adGroupCriterionService = $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupCriterionService::class);
    $operations = [];

    $devices = new Platform();
    // $devices->setPlatformName('Desktop');
    $devices->setId(30000);
    // $devices->setId($app_id);
    $biddableAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    $biddableAdGroupCriterion->setAdGroupId(52012184360);
    // $biddableAdGroupCriterion->setAdGroupId($adGroupId);
    $biddableAdGroupCriterion->setCriterion($devices);
    $biddableAdGroupCriterion->setBidModifier(1.5);
    // $biddableAdGroupCriterion->setBidModifier($bid_adjustment);

    $adGroupCriterionOperation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    $adGroupCriterionOperation->setOperand($biddableAdGroupCriterion);
    $adGroupCriterionOperation->setOperator(Operator::SET);
    $operations[] = $adGroupCriterionOperation;   
    $result = $adGroupCriterionService->mutate($operations);
```

I am having this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\ApiException:
>   [AdGroupCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED @
>   operations[0].operand.criterion; trigger:'Criterion']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  `AdGroupBidModifierService` instead.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/bidding#bid_modifiers

> Ad group level adjustments are accessible via **AdGroupBidModifierService**.
>
> Note: This section covers bid modifiers for Platform (campaign and ad group) [...]. For all **OTHER** criterion types, bid modifiers [...] are maintained via AdGroupCriterionService and specified via the bidModifier attribute of BiddableAdGroupCriterion.